# Updating a particular column of an array

Tags: julia

The following code does what I need it to do, but since I am bound to have the same task in future codes, I would like to know what the best way to achieve the outcome is:

```
p_last = fill(NaN, (n,periods-1)) 
p_first = ones(n) * 0.5
p = hcat(p_first,p_last)
```

Comment: Repeating myself from your previous post, `ones(n) * 0.5` is not a good way to create a vector of the number 0.5. Use `fill(0.5, n)` instead.

Answer (score 2):

There are many ways like:

```
p = fill(NaN, n, periods)
p[:, 1] .= 0.5
```

or

```
p = [j == 1 ? 0.5 : NaN for i in 1:n, j in 1:periods]
```

or similarly:

```
p = [ifelse(j == 1, 0.5, NaN) for i in 1:n, j in 1:periods]
```

All of them have the advantage that they allocate only one matrix. The first one is a bit faster but requires two statements.